# Rails include with options

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, include

Is it possible to limit an ActiveRecord `:include` to say only pull one record?

```
Item.find(:all,
    :include => [ :external_ratings, :photos => LIMIT 1 ])
```

I have a list of items, and each item has between 5 and 15 photos.  I want to load a photo id into memory, but I don't need all of them. I just want to preview the first one.

Is there a way to do this with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to do it directly, but as finding one record is only a single query, why not do it outside the include?

e.g

```
first_photo = Photo.find(records.first.photo_id)
```

After your main `find`

Comment: i'm sure this would work find, but if I have 50 entries it'll have to do it 50 different times.  It works fine right now with the include, it's just pulling into memory more info than I need.  ;-(

Comment: Can you clarify what you want in your question? You either want 1record or 50, but it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I changed it a little. But basically I'm retrieving a list of items, and each item has multiple images and ratings. I want all the ratings included, but I only need one image for each item, basically a preview.

Comment: Is there any ordering to the photos for each item?

Comment: i suppose using :include on photos isn't a huge footprint, i just thought there might be an easy way to limit it.

Comment: No easy way I think. It must be possible using SQL aggregate functions (using the AR :select and :group options) but can not quite get my head round it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to investigate the detailed query, but I'm thinking `find_by_sql` is in order for this particular case.